# ASP.NET Core MVC View Components

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core MVC (formerly MVC 6) there is a new area of functionality called View Components which appear to be a better alternative to Partial Views. I've seen the following [View Component Example](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc). But there doesn't seem much more information currently as to their usage.

I'm trying to evaluate if its worth using this pattern and if this can/(or is intended) to be used as a more baked in method to help with [donut caching](https://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 10):

View components are definitively great and it's certainly an improvement. The one big improvement is that you can run asynchronous operations on view components where [it wasn't possible with child actions](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601).

More information available here:

- [Exciting Things About ASP.NET vNext Series: MVC View Components](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/exciting-things-about-asp-net-vnext-series-mvc-view-components)

For donut caching, there are two separate issues filed that you can comment/track: [#1232](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1232) and [#536](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/536)

Comment: thanks I've read your article it's really helpful. But I was wondering more if there was a little more technical direction from Microsoft. Suspect its as its only just become beta.

Comment: @Tim I am not sure what exactly you are looking as everything is there :) what do you exactly mean by technical direction?

Comment: I take the point about async operations, but, you can also do that with @await Html.PartialAsync("PartialName"). Do ViewComponents offer any additional benefits over a async partial..? I am genuinely interested to know..

Comment: @McQuiggd, you can have business logic in the rendering of a ViewComponents. Partials require and already built model.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is available a brand new documentation from Microsoft:

- [View Components documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components).

In my opinion `ViewComponents` are very useful and flexible features. I like them, and I can recommend them.

However not always View Component is "a better alternative to Partial Views" - this will depend on your particular case.