# MVC 6 View Components vs. Partial Views: What is the difference? When should each be used?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

MVC 6 Introduced View components and said it is much stronger and flexible than partial views. Are view components meant to replace partial views? What is the difference and what kinds of situations call for each implementation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 6 View Components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989320/mvc-6-view-components)

Comment: I'd consider View Components a replacement for Child Actions; partial views are still useful when you're looking for the simple solution of adding a few common html elements.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to this link- https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components

> New to ASP.NET MVC 6, view components (VCs) are similar to partial views, but they are much more powerful. VCs include the same separation-of-concerns and testability benefits found between a controller and view. You can think of a VC as a mini-controller—it’s responsible for rendering a chunk rather than a whole response.

So it just a enhancement of partial view and another difference is when you use partial view you still have dependency on controller while in View Component you don't need a controller. So there is a separation of concern.

There is a detail post for ASP.NET View Components. 
http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/exciting-things-about-asp-net-vnext-series-mvc-view-components

Comment: you can call a (partial) view from an other directly, without using any controller. 
see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

so i can not understund the real advantage of component view :-(

Comment: Partial view can not have business logic while in view component you can have business logic.

Comment: I'm confused by this also. @JalpeshVadgama says w/ vc you don't have dependency on controller. So... you have dependency on ViewComponent instead? What's the benefit?

Comment: Let me give you an example- Let's say you are developing an e-commerce application where you are developing cart. In an earlier version of MVC, we used to have a partial view for that because we want to display it on multiple pages and that partial view is bind to an action in the controller or you need to pass model with every action where you are showing the cart.In view component, it does not depend on controller or models. You can have you will behave class inherited from the view component class and that will handle all the stuff. so You just need to put view component whenever you like.

Comment: It's like asp.net web form user component

Answer (score 10):

An example where you might want to use a `ViewComponent` as opposed to a `PartialView`:
*You need to write a bunch of business logic where for example you might need to contact a 3rd party web service and get the data and do something with it and then display this information.*

For the above scenario, sure you could write C# code in the partial view itself, but its ugly and also you want the code to be testable. So this is where a view component can be useful, i.e you can write all your business logic within a view component and return a view (this is of type `ViewViewComponentResult`).

View components are NOT the same as child actions.

Comment: Can you explain how ViewComponents are different from Child Actions?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch They are the same without the performance drawbacks. Although if you need to return a view component from Ajax I would stick with an Action.

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC Core there's `@inject` and dependency injection in views. You can wrap all the bunch of business logic and 3rd party web service in an interface and just have it as a dependency in a partial view. That will give you the same nicely separated and testable code as view components. So what's the point, really?

Comment: You don't need to write C# code in the views. Partial views can have a controller action too..

Answer (score 6):

`ViewComponent`s are also used when you need a partial view, that requires a model to be called in _Layout. To avoid writing C# code to create the model in the Layout, it's best to use a `ViewComponent` that can make use of the Services configured for the application, same as controllers, through dependency injection.