# Is there any good reason NOT to use a ViewComponent instead of a Partial View in core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to MVC and decided to start with .net-core, so I don't have much understanding of the differences in core vs. older versions. I did find the below question which offers some insight but hasn't helped me to decide whether I can basically ignore partial views.

[Why should we use MVC 6 Feature View Components over Partial View: What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823507/why-should-we-use-mvc-6-feature-view-components-over-partial-view-what-is-the-d)

My question is simply - if I can do something with a ViewComponent, is there any good reason not to?

Many Thanks!

Example provided below for context.

Main view calls:

ViewComponent:

```
<div class="modal-body" ID="modalPersonInner">
       @await Component.InvokeAsync("CreatePerson", new Person())
</div>
```

Versus Partial View:

```
<div class="modal-body" ID="modalPersonInner">
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("People/CreatePartialView", new Person());}
</div>
```

Javascript (personCreateForm is a form within the partial view/view component):

```
 var submitPersonCreate = function(evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).valid())
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("CreatePartial", "People")',
                data: $('#personCreateForm').serialize(),
                success(data) {
                    if (data === true)
                        window.location.reload();
                    else
                        $('#modalPersonInner').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    }
$('#personCreateForm').submit(submitPersonCreate);
```

Controller code:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePartial(
        [Bind("AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressLine3,AddressLine4,City,Country,Email,Forename,MobileNumber,Postcode,Region,Surname,TelephoneNumber")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(person);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(true);
        }
        //PARTIAL VIEW VERSION
        //return PartialView("People/CreatePartialView",person);

        //VIEWCOMPONENT VERSION
        return ViewComponent("CreatePerson", person);
    }
```

ViewComponent code:

```
 public class CreatePersonViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext db;

        public CreatePersonViewComponent(AppDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Person person )
        {

            return View(person ?? new Person());
        }

    }
```

And finally the Razor page which is the same for both:

```
@model Person

<form ID="personCreateForm">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Customer</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Forename" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Forename" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Forename" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Surname" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Surname" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Country" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Country" class="form-control" Value="UK" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Country" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Region" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Region" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Region" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="City" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AddressLine1" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="AddressLine1" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AddressLine1" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AddressLine2" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="AddressLine2" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AddressLine2" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Postcode" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Postcode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Postcode" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="MobileNumber" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="MobileNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MobileNumber" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TelephoneNumber" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="TelephoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TelephoneNumber" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Quite opinionated question you asked, not really suited for StackOverflow. But a ViewComponent needs to be instantiated and usually contains dependencies (injected via IoC container) and hence contains logic. A Partial view is just a template and should be used in place where you already have a model in place and just render it, without any application logic then you'll have less allocations and object instantiations per request

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a really good question.  Yes, there are cases where you are better off implementing your code with a partial view than with a View Component.  If the View Component isn't going to have any appreciable amount of logic (as is the case in your example) then you should use a partial view instead.

View Components are a great way to compartmentalize logic, and in some ways can be thought of as a partial view that contains it's own logic.  But if there isn't any logic that needs to be compartmentalized with the partial view then it's probably best to not use a View Component.  In such a case using a View Component increases the coding complexity (there is another place to look to see how the code works) but doesn't provide any real benefit.  In general, you should only increase code complexity to the extent that the benefits received from that added complexity are greater than the "cost" of that complexity.

I hope that doesn't sound too theoretical.   It basically boils down to this:  if there is logic that you want to package up with the partial view so that you can use that component over and over, then use a View Component, but if there isn't any logic that you need to package up with it then use a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that View Components still (as of July 2016) have some unsolved problems related to the javascript and css loading. Please check:
https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/11/26/view-components-in-asp-net-mvc-6

Comment: I presume these are now fixed?

Comment: Dejan, the linked article doesn't describe the issues you mentioned? What specifically are the issues you are referring to about problems relating to JS and CSS? Thanks