# Disadvantage of using only one ViewComponent Class for all view components in ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-8

I have an `asp.net core 8` application. I am using the ViewComponent Class to render my view components following this documentation: [aspnetcore-8 ViewComponents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-8.0). I have created an approach that will use only one ViewComponent Class so that I dont have to create a bunch of ViewComponent Classes everytime I added a new view component and also override the default search path.

**ViewComponent Code:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace UI.ViewComponents
{
    public class AppViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public AppViewComponent()
        {
            
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string baseFolder, string componentName, dynamic paramData) 
        { 
            return View($"/Views/{baseFolder}/Components/{componentName}.cshtml", paramData);
        }

    }
}
```

and the way Im using it is something like this in my `MainView.cshtml`:

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("App",
          new
          {
              baseFolder = "Provider",
              componentName = "Edit",
              paramData = (Provider: Model.provider, TestData: Model.testData)
          })



 @await Component.InvokeAsync("App",
          new
          {
              baseFolder = "Account",
              componentName = "Edit",
              paramData = (Account: Model.account)
          })
```

And in my component page, I have something like this which works perfectly:

```
@model (Provider provider, string[] testData)

<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.provider.Code" class="form-control border-end-0" id="code">
```

Is there any disadvantage of doing it like this? I searched over the internet, and I can't seem to find somebody document something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The case in your ViewComponent example doesn't have business logic , I guess you could use partial view instead. If you want do it like this, only one ViewComponent Class for all view components, you may encounter using one logic for all components.

You can have a look at these to know more, hope these can help:
[Partial views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223072/is-there-any-good-reason-not-to-use-a-viewcomponent-instead-of-a-partial-view-in)