# ViewComponent must have one public method named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke' - ASP.NET CORE (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am now designing a website using .NET6 and unlike older versions of ASP.NET Core, this version doesn't have methods like   `@{Html.RenderPartial("_ViewNamePartial")}`  so I'm using ViewComponents but when I try to render it, it throws an error :

**InvalidOperationException: View component 'aquaWeb.ViewComponents.ProductCardViewComponent' must have exactly one public method named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke'.**

Here is my code:

*Parent page that calls ViewComponent :*

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductCard");
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*View Component :*

```cs
public class ProductCardViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View());
        }
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the partial tag helper though?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Here is a comment which I'm sure explains things better than i will :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823923/10621507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the error was :

ViewComponent must have **ONLY** one public method named *InvokeAsync* or *Invoke*

**ViewComponent wants exactly just one method, not much or less.**

Going to read more careful next time...

I changed my ViewComponent class from this :

```cs
public class ProductCardViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View());
        }
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

To this:

```cs
public class ProductCardViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View());
        }
    }
```

and it's working pretty well