# Error: RZ3901 View component 'ViewComponents.RegularPaymentGridViewComponent' must have exactly one public method named 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I got 567 times of this error. I just updated VS 2022 17.7.5 to 17.8.6. After that I got this error

```
Error   RZ3901  View component 'Scribe.Web.ViewComponents.RegularPaymentGridViewComponent' must have exactly one public method named 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync'. Web C:\Users\smayd\OneDrive\Masaüstü\ScribeWeb\Scribe\Web\SDKRAZORGENERATE  1
```

in my project, also This error

> 'This solution contains packages with vulnerabilities. Manage NuGet Packages ' appear top of the solution explorer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Cap.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ViewComponent must have one public method named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke' - ASP.NET CORE (.NET 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366226/viewcomponent-must-have-one-public-method-named-invokeasync-or-invoke-asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following question is similar to yours:

[ViewComponent must have one public method named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke' - ASP.NET CORE (.NET 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366226/viewcomponent-must-have-one-public-method-named-invokeasync-or-invoke-asp)

Have a look at the accepted answer and see if it helps out solving your issue.

**Update based on comment below**

I suspect the issue is because the .Net version you are using are getting out of date. I strongly suggest you migrate/upgrade to a newer version like
minimum .Net 6 for better support.

[image]

Comment: Actually problem is not in the code. Because codes are belong to the company. I just updated visual studio and got these errors and not only one error I got 507 same errors. I passes to older version again, then the project couldnt open with this error 'Microsoft .Net SDK couldnt found'

Comment: What .Net version are you using?

Comment: .net 4.6.1 and also .net core 2

Comment: I have updated my answer. I believe the issue you are having is due to older .Net versions.

Comment: Yes you are right. But my company works with that technology that's why I also need to :( How about passing older version of VS ?

Comment: Passing older version solved!